# Is there a URL scheme for sending an SMS to multi-recipients?

Tags: applications, iphone

I just got quickpick from the app store, and of course I have it doing my basic call this person (tel://A), text this person(sms://B), but I would like to know, is there a URL scheme for SMS with multiple recipients? I've tried mms://A+B but it doesn't recognize mms:// as a command.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

If `sms://` launches Messages (and it does), then you don't need an `mms://` handler, because `sms://` launches Messages but doesn't determine the message type. Simply tap the camera icon and choose the photo to send once Messages launches.

Protocol handlers like `tel://` and `sms://` are just glorified urls, like http://www.askdifferent.com/, and they were not designed with multiple resources in mind. Resources being domains, files, etc. Note that you cannot request two files from within a single URL.

Example: You cannot do something like: http://www.askdifferent.com/images/uploadedscreenshot1.png+uploadedscreenshot2.png

I've attempted various delimiters for multiple recipients, such as `%20`, `,`, `|`, `+`, and `&`, and none of them working. I would not be surprised if there is no way to specify multiple recipients via the `sms://` protocol URI.

Comment: Yeah, what I meant was just a SMS for multiple recipients.